# Was my answer downvoted due to anti-semitism?

Tags: support, down-votes

My answer:

[Where is a celebration-free, little-to-no Christmas skiing destination during the holiday season?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148863/where-is-a-celebration-free-little-to-no-christmas-skiing-destination-during-th/148898#148898)

received 3 downvotes with no explanation.  It also received comments complaining about "Israeli occupation".

Do we have anti-semites on the site that downvote everything that mentions Israel?  Can anything be done about that?

Comment: Don't the first two comments on your answer describe good reasons for the down-votes? BTW, you get a -1 on this question from me for trying to deprecate political critisism as religious bashing. It is not anti-semite (bashing of jews) to talk critically about the politics of Israel.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, thanks for bringing this up on meta.

> My answer [Where is a celebration-free, little-to-no Christmas skiing destination during the holiday season?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148863/where-is-a-celebration-free-little-to-no-christmas-skiing-destination-during-th/148898#148898) received 3 downvotes with no explanation.

Whilst not personally downvoting, I find an explanation in the comments which state:

> I don't know about the Mount Hermon area in particular, **but Christmas is absolutely huge in Israel** -- not so much locals celebrating, but tourists packing the place.

The question specifically asked for a *little-to-no Christmas skiing destination*.

From a quick Google search from [tourist Israel](https://www.touristisrael.com/christmas-in-israel-the-holy-land/3103/):

> Christmas in Israel, is truly Christmas in the Holy Land, a magically meaningful experience for Christians. Less commercialized than in much of the Western world because Judaism and Islam are the two main religions of Israel, **Christmas in Israel is meaningful for its historic significance as the land where the Christmas story took place.**

That is the obvious reason for the downvotes, it doesn't answer the question.

> Do we have anti-semites on the site that downvote everything that mentions Israel?  Can anything be done about that?

**We don't have anti-semites on this site**. [Searching for *Israel*](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=israel)  and sorting by votes yields a question with a score of 60 (at the time of writing) and I see no issues there.

**What if someone is being anti-semitic?**

This is against the [Code of Conduct](https://travel.stackexchange.com/conduct):

> **No bigotry.**
>
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or **religion** — and those are just a few examples.

To report a Code of Conduct violation use [Contact Us](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact) and select *I want to report a Code of Conduct violation*.

Comment: Your google search does not reveal the fact Christmas is *not* celebrated in any primarily Jewish areas... you will only see it in non-Jewish tourist areas.  In fact it would be offensive to celebrate Christmas in most areas, including this ski area.

Comment: To be fair, we've had numerous issues over the years with comments re Israel, Palestine, Saudi Arabia, Iran, in terms of legitimacy, naming, whether they exist(!), and who is good/evil.  Solution tho: Don't engage, just flag 'em.

Answer (score 3):

> Do we have anti-semites on the site that downvote everything that mentions Israel?

It is impossible to answer this. Votes are anonymous, and although it would be nice and courteous to say the least, voters are not obliged to explain the reason for the downvote.

Please do not try to reverse-engineer the reason for downvotes. It is impossible to know for sure why people do what they do, even if they explain their reasoning.

Please do not make mountains out of a molehills. It is ludicrous to conclude that the people who are downvoting you are antisemites, based on just three downvotes on one post.

Trust me, you'll have a much better time on SE if you do this.

> Can anything be done about that?

Yes. **You** have several options:

1. [Flag for moderator attention](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
2. [Contact community managers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/contact)

We will most definitely try to help. However, keep in mind that results may vary. It is virtually impossible to unmask potential antisemites on Travel.SE using a single data point consisting of three downvotes on one post.